# Auth0 on local chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, auth0

I'm working on a Chrome extension for a university project. The extension is pretty much ready, but the client asked me to implement Auth0 for keeping track of every user configuration with a secure login. As I try to learn how Auth0 works, it seems that Auth0 is asking for **Application URIs.** However, when I try to use the local URL that the extension uses, for example: *chrome-extension://"extension-id"/*, it gives me this error: **Error! Payload validation error: 'Object didn't pass validation for format absolute-https-uri-or-empty: chrome-extension://"my extension ID"/options.html' on property initiate_login_uri (Initiate login URI, must be HTTPS).** So I think it is not possible to implement Auth0 for this type of application because it works locally and not from a server (it connects to an API if it's necessary to know).
Is there any simple way to use auth0 in this extension? or i should look for another options, if so, any ideas?

I create a new project on auth0 page and get a domain and token for it, but when it asked me for Callback URLs or Login URI it just doesnt work.
The extension is made on JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.